# uniqueIdentifier vs. indentifierForVendor and Apple rejection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I have a question about `uniqueIdentifier` vs `identifierforVendor`.  We use the UDID for login identification purposes and we are in the process of switching over to the new iOS 6 version of forVendor...

My questions are this
1) Is Apple rejecting apps that are still using uniqueIdentifier?
2) How can they reject this seeing as they don't allow first generation ipads to go up to 6.0?

PS - also found that `identifierforVendor` doesn't always work in 6.0, looks like it was resolved in 6.0.1

Here is the code I am using... do you think it will get rejected?

```
static inline NSString* UniqueDeviceId() {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0.1" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
        return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

While I can't speak for the Apple review team. it is unlikely you will be rejected for using this deprecated API as long as your app supports a version of iOS that doesn't have the alternative.

I would update your code to properly check for the new method:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)]) {
    return [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
} else {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... the only problem with this approach is that in 6.0 we are finding that identifierForVendor will sometimes return blank.  Here is a bug report on this http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2049403

Answer (score 0):

now Apps are not permitted to access the UDID and must not use the uniqueIdentifier method of UIDevice. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];
```

and must to add ADSupport framework